# Travel within Schengen with Titre de Sejour, but expired passport

Tags: visas, schengen, passports, france, residency

I am a non-EU national, with a valid Titre de Sejour in France (which is a long-term residency visa).

My passport has expired and it takes time to update it. Can I travel (for one week) within the Schengen area with Titre de Sejour only, or perhaps together with an expired passport?

In this [website](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-nationals/index_en.htm), it's stated that both a valid passport and a visa/residency-card is needed.

Comment: Where in the Schengen area are you going? In some countries you're legally required to have a valid passport on your person at all times.

Comment: Sweden. Do I need a valid passport with air travel?

Comment: ID requirements for internal Schengen flights are determined by the airlines.  Some will require a valid passport; others might not.

Comment: I see. You mean there is no ID control by airport staff for internal EU flights, other than airlines?

Comment: I think that varies by airport or by country.  I'm waiting even as I type at the gate for a domestic flight in Greece.  I showed no ID at the security screening, only my boarding pass.  But I couldn't say that the same would be true for all internal Schengen flights.